# VBA Labeling works on some symbol classes but not other

Tags: arcmap, vba

VBA Labeling formatting works on some symbol classes but not others.

For some symbol classes it will work but others it won't register the formatting and I can't figure out why!

```
CLR red = '56' green = '168' blue ='0'>" & [LOCA_ID] & /CLR
```

This is the section of VBA not working, obviously it is closed off in the VBA statement.

[LOCA_ID] is string.

Updated:

```vb
Function FindLabel ([LOCA_ID],[SPEC_DPTH],[ERES_NAME],[ERES_RTXT],[ERES_RUNI])
  FindLabel = "<CLR red ='255'>" & [LOCA_ID] & "</CLR>" + " / " + "Sample Depth - " + [SPEC_DPTH] & vbnewline & [ERES_NAME] + " - " + [ERES_RTXT] + [ERES_RUNI] 
End Function
```

[[image: Example of how some symbol classes work and others don't [1]]

Any ideas??

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full expression, as currently you are missing end tags which would explain why it is not running, but this could be a simple typo introduced by you copying and pasting? Can't tell until we see the full code

Comment: When i past the full expression in the CLR section dosent show up. but you can see it in the image in the lables that dont work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are any instances of special characters (& and <) in [LOCA_ID], the formatting will fail. You have to replace them dynamically with code like this:

```
Function FindLabel ([LABELFIELD])
  NewString = Replace([LABELFIELD],"&","&amp;")  
  FindLabel = "<ITA>" & NewString & "</ITA>"
End Function

Replace "&" with "&amp;" and "<" with "&lt;"
```

See [this page](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/using-text-formatting-tags-about-text-formatting-t.htm) for more information.

Comment: No, LOCA_ID is only numbers and text, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Take a closer look at your data. The values that are failing include the string "<0.05 mg/kg". That's the special character that is causing the problem.